# Page numbers disappear - fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

When I compile this code, the numbering disappear in all the pages

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel} 
    \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[french]{nomencl}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setlength{\headheight}{52pt} % If I dont write this line ,text overlap with the header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{Rapport de stage}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}}

    \hypersetup{
    pdfborder={0 0 0},colorlinks=false
    }


    \FrenchFootnotes
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5cm}
     \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}

     \lipsium


\end{document}
```

Could you explain me where is the problem? ( Even when I remove footnotes I still have this problem)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Compilable code: starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page was too long, thereby displacing the page number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[top=52pt, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{Rapport de stage}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}}

\hypersetup{
    pdfborder={0 0 0},colorlinks=false
}


\FrenchFootnotes
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
        \lipsum


\end{document}
```